# Need to display value upto two decimal digits in SSRS report

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I need to display discount % up to two places of decimal in a SSRS report. The current expression that i am using is `"Fields!Discount.Value"` and its generating inconsistent values in the report.

Comment: if your value is already the expected percentage then i suppose create a field and multiply by 100.... format the display as %

Comment: If you field has percentages as an amount <1 (e.g. 0.75 represents 75%) then format the textfield as p2. If it's just a number format it as f2

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. Yes, the required field has values <1 (e.g.5%,8%).. So i need to display them as 0.05 form limited only upto 2 places of decimals. The current expression is not displaying in this manner for all the values as i am getting some of the values as 0.08000000001.Can you please suggest an expression for it, to limit the values only upto 2 digits after decimal .

Comment: how is your 0.08000000001 supposed to be displayed? As just 0.08 as 0.08% or 8% . Also is the column in your dataset a number or string? Also, have a look at this.. http://www.sqlsafety.com/?p=231

Answer (score 0):

In the top designer bar in the number field, change it from Default to Number. Then use the little decimal buttons to adjust how many decimals you will allow to be shown.

I don't have enough rep to post images, but screen shot link below.

[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOmFF.png)